Level od data in rows
I need sql query that from data:
1.2.4.1.1
1.2.4.1.2
1.2.4.4
1.2.4.4.1
...
Takes all data except
1.2.4.4.1 because he is part of
1.2.4.4,
So I need the highest level of every row that has 1.2.4 in root.
I tried something with "not exists" an I got data that have all correct rows and 1.2.4.4.1 , but I want to skip 1.2.4.4.1 and get only :
1.2.4.1.1
1.2.4.1.2
1.2.4.4

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

If you want to return all the rows where the rows do not start with a sub-string in another row then you can use NOT EXISTS and a correlated sub-query:
SELECT *
FROM   table_name t
WHERE  NOT EXISTS(
         SELECT 1
         FROM   table_name x
         WHERE  t.value LIKE x.value || '.%'
       )

or an anti-join:
SELECT t.*
FROM   table_name t
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table_name x
       ON t.value LIKE x.value || '.%'
WHERE  x.value IS NULL

or, from Oracle 12, you may be able to use MATCH_RECOGNIZE for row-by-row pattern matching (assuming your full-stop delimited terms are all single digits):
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
       MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
         ORDER BY value
         ALL ROWS PER MATCH
         PATTERN (first_row {- starts_with_first_row* -} )
         DEFINE
           starts_with_first_row AS value LIKE first_row.value || '.%'
       )

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT '1.2.4.1.1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1.2.4.1.2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1.2.4.4'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1.2.4.4.1' FROM DUAL;

All output:



VALUE




1.2.4.1.1


1.2.4.1.2


1.2.4.4



fiddle
